# Insert values into table from multiple sources

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to insert data into a 3 columns of a table. 2 columns are from other table and the third value is an array variable. I need to process this within a loop. Can anyone help ?

I want something like below,

```
Insert into table_name (col1,col2,col3)  values  ((Select a,b from Source_table),array_variable(i));
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into table_name (col1, col2, col3) 
Select a, b, 'static value'
from Source_table
```

Comment: I am getting 'missing expression' error when I tried your query. Is that because the array_variable(i) is not present in the Source_table. ?

Comment: If your variable is a string you need to put in in quotes. See my update.